# Is it possible to configure uboot without the "Yun Serial Terminal" sketch by using the hardware serial on pins 0 and 1 instead?

Tags: pins, arduino-yun, uart

[Trying to rescue a Yun with the 1.5.3 image.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunUBootReflash)

It's not possible to upload the required "Yun Serial Terminal" sketch  because the device hangs at U-Boot (hence the rescue attempt).

Using putty serial with:
Pin 0 (Rx)
Pin 1 (Tx)
Baud: 250000
8N1

This capture shows the result (which is the best I can find so far).
How do I properly connect to the serial console using the GPIO pins?

[image: Putty Serial 250000 8N1]

Comment: Hold the MCU in RESET to prevent it interfering.